# Unable to open mobile camera in Ionic app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-camera, ionic4

My objective is to upload multiple files either via camera or file storage, I'm using ng2FileSelect for uploading multiple files to the server via Ionic app, this is the HTML for it:

```
<input (change)="upload()" type="file" ng2FileSelect
[uploader]="uploader" multiple accept="image/*" capture="environment">
```

On running it on localhost on chrome, it is successfully giving options, either to open mobile camera or select files from storage. But on testing it on Ionic DevApp or on android device(via APK), it is directly opening file storage and not giving option of opening mobile camera. Is it possible to achieve the said objective with the above input tag, or I have to use a separate method for uploading files from the camera such as Cordova camera plugin, etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng2FileSelect is specific for browsers it may create a problem on the native device. My suggestion is to use cordova camera plugin.

You can install the plugin via this commands

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
npm install @ionic-native/camera
```

It Supports following platforms

- Android
- Browser
- iOS
- Windows

Usage

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';

constructor(private camera: Camera) { }

...


const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
}

this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
 // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
 // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
 let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
}, (err) => {
 // Handle error
});
```